# How would I define multiple answers based on which checkbox is selected in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I currently have this formula set into my cell:

```
=if(G32 = TRUE, "12", "")
```

Thus, if `G32` is checked it will display `12`. However, I want to allow the formula to react with multiple check boxes each giving its own data.

Like,

```
=if(G30 = TRUE, "7", "")
```

So if `G30` where to be checked it would instead display a 7. I don't need them to happen at the same time. Like they shouldn't really both display. However, I want them in the same cell to pop up independently dependent on which ever cell is checked. I'm fairly new to Google Sheets formulas and I can't figure this one out.

Comment: Welcome to Webapps. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet and include an example of a successful outcome. Your mention G23=>"12", and G30=>"7", but you don't explain the significance if this number.

Comment: You can try `=switch()` maybe ? I made an answer on a similar problem https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/136190/problem-with-nested-if-statement-on-google-sheets/136196#136196

Answer (score 1):

I am the OP. I tried switch and it almost worked but I couldn't quite string it out right with that function. I searched through a function list however and found the IFS function and that seems to be working wonderfully. Thank you for trying to help pjmg. Sorry I didn't have more information and then quickly worked it out myself. I was stressed with trying to figure it out and tried to seek aid, and its good to know of this resource here if I ever need help again! I hope you have a wonderful day.

This can be closed.

Comment: You can maybe share your formula and choose this answer to close the question. Thanks !

Comment: It must have been an IF(and(A1=true,B1=true),"A+B",IF(and(A1=true,C1=true),"A+C",IF(etcetera)